# Query for documents where field in array is greater than x

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a hard time understanding how to do queries on arrays. A basic example, If I take this document:

```
Man
 children
  Frank
   age: 33
  Anna
   age: 28
```

How do I find all the children who have an age greater than 30?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: Something like `db.collection_name.aggregate([
    {$match: {'children.age': {$gt:30}},
    {$project: {
        children: {$filter: {
            input: '$children',
            as: 'child',
            cond: {$gt: ['$$child.age', 30]}
        }},
        _id: 0
    }}
])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query of @Veeram works pretty well:

```
db.getCollection('men').aggregate([ 
{ $match: {'children.age': {$gt:30}} }, 
{ $project: { children: {$filter: { input: '$children', as: 'child', cond: {$gt: ['$$child.age', 30]} }}, _id: 0 }}
])
```

This [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) helped me to understand.

Comment: I think you meant $$child.age but that's OK.   For clarity, the $match will find all docs where at least one of the children is > 30, but that will yield the whole doc with the whole child array possibly including children <= 30.   So the $filter is required to weed out <= 30.

Comment: Thank you @BuzzMoschetti